# Create function out of parameters

Tags: windows, batch-file

Hello I got a question regarding functions within a batch file. I have the following setup:

```
echo off
set dSource=%1
set dTarget=%2
set fType=%3
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /a-d /b /s %dSource%\%fType%') do (
    copy /V "%%f" %dTarget%\tempsrc 2>nul
)
```

I can call this batch file with the following parameters:

```
test.bat "C:\Batch" "C:\Output" "text.xml"
```

Is there a posibility that I can have, like in Javascript or any other programming language, a function which takes the parameter as input so that I can make a call like this:

```
functionName(dSource,dTarget,fType1)
functionName(dSource,dTarget,fType2)
etc..
```

Otherwise I have to do it like this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /a-d /b /s %dSource%\%fType1%') do (
    copy /V "%%f" %dTarget%\tempsrc 2>nul
)
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /a-d /b /s %dSource%\%fType2%') do (
    copy /V "%%f" %dTarget%\tempsrc 2>nul
)
```

Which is very insufficient

Comment: Don't use shell script (batch). If you want real functions, the answer is very easy: Just use PowerShell.

Comment: mmm oke! I will have a look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do with [label which you can invoke](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-functions.html) with `call ::label`:

```
call ::funct param_1 param_2

exit /b %errorlevel%

:funct [dsource ftype]
echo off
set dSource=%1
set dTarget=%2
set fType=%3
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /a-d /b /s %dSource%\%fType%') do (
    copy /V "%%f" %dTarget%\tempsrc 2>nul
)
```

And you need to set `exit /b` before starting functions definitions in order to prevent them to execute twice.

Comment: Thank you. But how are the param_1 and param_2 used? Where do you reference to it within the `set` or `for` loop?

Comment: @Rotan075 - this is up to you. `%1` will be the first argument passed to the function `%2` the second and so on. If you want to use the command line arguments you need can just use `call ::funct %1 %2`

Comment: awesome! Thank you that is what I am looking for!

Comment: As you can see, this is pretty painful compared to a language that has actual functions.

Comment: Why do you state double-colons `call ::funct`?

Comment: @aschipfl - it is working with double semicolons too.

Answer (score 2):

Batch files do not have true functions (in the sense of returning a value); they do, however, have the equivalent of procedures or subroutines, which can take parameters. Subroutines/procedures are invoked by the `CALL` command. If you do not need to pass information back to the caller from the callee, the `CALL`ed routine may be stored in a separate `.BAT` or `.CMD` file; if you need to pass information back (a "function hack"), the subroutine must be a labelled block in the caller file. For the latter, see [the DOSTips Batch Function Tutorial](http://www.dostips.com/DtTutoFunctions.php).

(For what it's worth, I do agree with Bill_Stewart's recommendation for using PowerShell in preference to batch.)